# How can I filter users by group membership across multiple OU's?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I have a user query that can't be done at an OU level.  I am trying to only return users where they are a member of a group (I need to filter by the group string value, not the actual group object).  Here is what it currently looks like:

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://foo.net/DC=appName,DC=domainName,DC=com", Username, Password)) {
    using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher()) {
        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";
        searcher.SearchRoot = entry;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");

        foreach (SearchResult sr in searcher.FindAll()) {
            var member = GetSearchResultProperty(sr, "memberOf");
        }
    }
}
```

This query goes across multiple OU's where there are different user and group containers.

Is there a way I can filter on the `memberOf` property when I execute my query (without specifying any sort of OU)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what I am trying to do isn't possible at the time of query execution because the `memberOf` property needs to be a full path to a group.  In my case, I don't actually care about the group object, but, rather the group name (each OU will have different groups, but, could have the same group name).  I had to take a different approach to solve this which could have performance implications later on.  Just in case someone else finds this question looking for an answer, here is how I am solving it as of now:

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://foo.net/DC=appName,DC=domainName,DC=com", Username, Password)) {
    using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher()) {
        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user))";
        searcher.SearchRoot = entry;
        searcher.PageSize = 5000;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(DirectoryConstants.AD_PROPERTY_MEMBER_OF);
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(DirectoryConstants.AD_PROPERTY_DISPLAY_NAME);

        foreach (SearchResult sr in searcher.FindAll()) {
            //The memberOf property will be a string array if the user is in multiple groups.
            string[] memberOf = GetSearchResultProperties(sr, DirectoryConstants.AD_PROPERTY_MEMBER_OF);
            //Check if the user is in the group by analyzing the string.
            var group = memberOf.FirstOrDefault(m => m.StartsWith(string.Format("CN={0},", groupName)));

            if (group != null) {
                //The user is in the group!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is an extremely old post, but I just ran into the same problem.  Your solution is also explained another way here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05c5fbe2-3ad3-4ab0-8bf8-c5d623388a18/directorysearcher-filter-options-how-to-verify-if-the-user-belongs-to-an-active-directory-user?forum=aspactivedirectory

Answer (score 1):

Just add another term to the filter:

```
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=myGroup))";
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I believe the `memberOf` might need the full group object path instead of just the name.  If I use just the `user` filter I get back all the users across the multiple OU's.  But, once I add the name of the group to the filter like you suggested above, I don't get any results.  Here is the string showing group membership from an AD explorer:  `CN=myGroup,CN=groups,OU=theOU,DC=appName,DC=domainName,DC=com`

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the full distinguished name of the group in your search filter, as the memberOf property will contain that value.

```
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=myGroup,CN=groups,OU=theOU,DC=appName,DC=domainName,DC=com))";
```

**EDIT :**

My apologies, as I misread the question. Without including an OU, the only other way of doing this is taking the opposite approach, and locating the group object first :

```
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(name=Your Group Name)"
```

Then iterate through the `DirectoryEntry` using it's properties :

```
foreach(object dn in group.Properties["member"] )
{
    string DistinguishedName = dn.ToString();
}
```

If you're retrieving more than 1,000+ users though, you'll need to take a more segmented approach, which is detailed [in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180907%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: In my original post I said I can't perform the search at the OU level, so, it looks like it isn't possible to filter on group the way I want to.